# MySQL order by count of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have:

```
   SELECT bloggers.*, 
          COUNT(post_id) AS post_count
     FROM bloggers 
LEFT JOIN blogger_posts ON bloggers.blogger_id = blogger_posts.blogger_id
 GROUP BY bloggers.blogger_id
 ORDER BY post_count
```

That returns all bloggers ordered by their post count.
What if I want just some bloggers but still ordered by the same criteria (for example those whose AUX field is equal to 3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause should come immediately before the `GROUP BY` clause. When in doubt about something as straightforward as syntax, the place to look is the manual.

[MySQL Manual :: SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
   SELECT bloggers.*, 
          COUNT(post_id) AS post_count
     FROM bloggers 
LEFT JOIN blogger_posts ON bloggers.blogger_id = blogger_posts.blogger_id
    WHERE bloggers.AUX = 3
 GROUP BY bloggers.blogger_id
 ORDER BY post_count
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I had read the manual and still couldn't get it.